# yadcf DataTables Tags for MySQL Database (Ajax, serverside False)

Tags: mysql, ajax, datatable, datatables, yadcf

Using `DataTables v1.10.13-dev`

Along with `Yet Another DataTables Column Filter - (yadcf) v0.9.1`

Initializing my DataTable like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable;
oTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
            "pageLength": 50,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
    ....
```

Initializing yadcf in the same function immediately after like so

```
 yadcf.init(oTable, [{
                     //  column_number: 1,
                                            filter_type: "select",
                        column_data_type: "html",
                        html_data_type: "text",
                        filter_default_label: "Select tag"
                    }]);
```

It's initalizing all fine, so no issues there. I tested it with things such as column data input, column select input, it all works.

Here's how my datatable (and MySQL Database) is currently looking (without yadcf):

[image]

I'm looking to add another column, after `Days Remaining`, which is for `tags`

Here's a yadcf demo screenshot for a visual of what I'm looking to create.

[image]

Notice, of course, the last column, `tags`.

I've searched through the documentation, and through google.. but still am unaware of how to add tags in conjunction with my MySQL Database.

My question is, where are the `tags` or `categories` coming from?
Is this just as simple as adding another column in my `Inventory` table, named `Tags` or `Categories`, and categorize my tags that way?

As you can see on my yadcf initialization, I first tested this on `column_number: 1`, which is my SKU

And it appeared, but nothing was in the drop down, and it was obviously incomplete.

[image]

Then again, `SKU` is a `Unique` column in my MySQL database, so this initialization is not for its intended purpose.

Can anyone shine some light on this for me? How do `yadcf` `tags` work in conjunction with a live MySQL Database.

I have 2000+ items to categorize, and want to make sure I have a grasp of this before undertaking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yadcf uses `column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text",`for the tag column because the structure of that column is in HTML format as following (and not a simple string inside the `<td></td>`

Like this:

`<span class="label lightblue">Tag2</span>
 <span class="label lightblue">Tag3</span>`

I made the spans to look as they are with a bit of css

```
    .label {
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        -moz-border-radius: 1em; /* for mozilla-based browsers */
        -webkit-border-radius: 1em; /* for webkit-based browsers */
        border-radius: 1em; /* theoretically for *all* browsers*/
    }

    .label.lightblue {
        background-color: #99CCFF;
    }
```

This is a few words about the yadcf showcase page,

---

So either decorate your html by hand and use something like `column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text",`

Or with [datatables Column rendering](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/61f8ee76d432f129490d77a2b96339e305f1b305/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L71) and use `column_data_type: 'rendered_html'` [read docs for more info](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/61f8ee76d432f129490d77a2b96339e305f1b305/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L71)

Comment: Okay, I believe I understand now. This makes sense I was just confused as to how to make it work with a live MySQL table. So basically I need to create another column in my MySQL table, presumably a `TEXT` data type, and include a block of HTML in each row with the entries `Tag` or `Category`, and yadcf will work its magic if I have it set to the appropriate `column_data_type` and `html_data_type`.  I'll give it a whirl thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I also recommend you to read the docs of yadcf and go over the showcase pages